# need help pick up multiple log files from a directory and grep the error

Tags: linux, shell

This is what i have so far my question is how do i add directory in script where all the log files

```
#!/bin/bash
while true ; do
    tail ~/Path
    grep -o 'ERROR No appender named [MicromuseAppender] could be found' ' /dyn/logfiles/ (path)' &> /dyn/logfiles/.log
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo Error found
        break
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: What is `' /dyn/logfiles/ (path)'` supposed to be there? What is `tail ~/Path` supposed to doing? Are you asking where to put the path to the log files in this script to have `grep` operate on the log files?

Comment: `for file in \`ls dir\`; do <whatever> done`

Comment: @ODelibalta Don't parse `ls` output and don't use backticks.

Comment: @ott-- fair 'nuff .. `#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES ` if that does not work for you, I do not know what does (:

Answer (score 1):

go to the destination folder and grep from all files

```
grep 'ERROR No appender named [MicromuseAppender] could be found' $PATH/*
```

The output is like

```
<Filename>:<line which contains the grep'ed string>
```

To get file names only in which the error string is occurred atleast once.

```
grep 'ERROR No appender named [MicromuseAppender] could be found' $PATH/* | cut -f1 -d: | sort | uniq
```